# SQL multiple column equality

Tags: mysql, sql, type-conversion, where-clause, sql-injection

**This is not a real production code! this was presented in a Google CTF to find and learn about application vulnerabilities and how to protect from them**

I'm trying to understand a weird SQL syntax I've seen on Google CTF. Let's say we set up a table like this:

```
create table users (
username varchar(20), 
password varchar(20) );

insert into users (username, password) 
values ('admin', 'supersecretrandompassword');
```

Now, if we run the following query:

```
select * 
from users 
where username = 'admin'
and password = username = '';
```

It will retrieve the username and password of the `admin` user!
It doesn't work, however, when doing `password = username = 9` (or any other number).

So my question is, how does the last clause evaluated and why does it work with strings but not with numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you run this query in the first place?

Comment: The password should never be stored in the database. In this case salt it, and hash it with at least as 160-bit hash.

Comment: Did you try `0` like: `password = username = 0`?

Comment: @TheImpaler as I wrote in the question, this was a Google CTF competition, a dedicated application/environment to find/practice security vulnerabilities in order to learn how to protect from them. It's **not** a production code of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boolean expression `password = username = ''` is evaluated from left to right, like:

```
(password = username) = ''
```

So:

- if `password = username` is `true` the expression is equivalent to `1 = ''`
- if `password = username` is `false` the expression is equivalent to `0 = ''`

In both cases `''` is [implicitly converted](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) to the number `0` prior to the comparison.

In your case I suspect that `password = username` is `false`, so the `WHERE` clause is equivalent to:

```
where username = 'admin' and 0 = 0;
```

or simpler:

```
where username = 'admin';
```

Comment: This answer makes sense but I fail to see the use case. Is the OP trying SQL Injection on purpose?

Comment: @TheImpaler I have no idea. I only answer the question: *how does the last clause evaluated...* Most probably the OP found someone else's code and is just curious.

Comment: @forpas what confused me was that even when I tried to compare the columns to a non-empty string the expression still evaluated to `true`, and now I see why: when MySQL evaluates the expression, it tries to parse the string, in order to cast it to a number, and since the string doesn't start with a number - it is casted to 0. Thanks!